# Overloading standard parantheses ("()") in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

This should be very simple but I failed to google it: How (if at all) can I overload the parantheses operator in Python? So that this code will make sense:

```
my_new_object = my_new_class()
x = my_new_object(5)
```

Comment: There is no operator "overloading".  Are you trying to create a callable object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define [`__call__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) on your class.

For example

```
>>> class Multiplier(object):
...    def __init__(self, num):
...        self.num = num
...    def __call__(self, other):
...        return self.num*other
...
>>> mul5 = Multiplier(5)
>>> mul5(6)
30
```

Answer (score 8):

Define [`__call__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) on your class:

```
class MyNewClass(object):
    def __call__(self, x):
        return x
```

Answer (score 5):

You should look at the "Callable types" section of [this document](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy). In particular, your class could implement [`__call__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__).